# Is it possible to read spin text from 1 file & write it in another text file without bracket in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck & i need your help guys. Here is what i want this program to do. I have 1 text file named spin.txt which contains spin text like {something there|Source|something here} baz {why not find out more|these guys} & i have another text file named write.txt now i want to read from spin.txt file & write it to write.txt file. What i have done. Everything is working fine but the only problem i am getting is when writing to write.txt file it adds bracket & ' like this - [' wrote here'] but i don't want this i only want to write that text. I am using python 3x on windows 10.

```
**My code :-**

import re
import itertools

p = re.compile("(\{[^\}]+\}|[^\{\}]*)")

spin_comments  =open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\spin.txt","r")
file = str(spin_comments.readlines())

frags = p.split(file)

def options(s):
    if len(s) > 0 and s[0] == '{':
        return [opt for opt in s[1:-1].split('|')]
    return [s]

opt_lists = [options(frag) for frag in frags]

write_text = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\write.txt","w")


for spec in itertools.product(*opt_lists):
    a = ''.join(spec)
    write_text.write(a + '\n')
    print(a)
write_comment.close()
```

Comment: `opt_lists` is a `list` of `list`, so consequentially `spec` is always a `list`, hence the reason you see the square brackets. You should change your data structure or strip the square brackets from `a` (like `a = ''.join(spec)[1:-1]`).

Comment: yeah but it just removes brackets & not ' this. I want to remove both of them.

Comment: nevermind it's done. Thank you so much for your help @Bit

Answer (score 0):

''.join(spec)[2:-2]

Just changing this in code it works. Thanks for reply @bit

Comment: FYI: Have a look at what `readlines` returns - your extra characters come from this. Try using `read` or iterate over the lines if more than one.

Comment: @GlennRogers no, he's parsing with regex right after so it doesn't matter. The extra characters appear due to the way that the output of the `options` function are handled.